Download passworded RAR-arhive from google.drive
My app (written in Visual Basic) downloads passworded RAR-archive from google.drive. Here is 2 examples of code that worked for some time and then stopped (google changed something). File is small, approx. 1.5mb. When I put my link to webbrowser - it opens a web page with text something like "we can't check your file for viruses bla bla bla" and one button "download anyway". After pressing button - file downloaded without any problems. How to do it programmically???  One time adding "&confirm=yes" to link solved my problem, but now this solution stopped working again.
Anybody have ideas without using google api? Looking for small and elegant solution (if possible).
v1
Dim fileReader As New WebClient()
Dim fileAddress = "https://drive.google.com/my_file_direct_link"
fileReader.DownloadFile(fileAddress, SaveFileDialog1.FileName)

v2
Dim fileReader As New WebClient()
Dim fileAddress = "https://drive.google.com/my_file_direct_link&confirm=yes"
fileReader.DownloadFile(fileAddress, SaveFileDialog1.FileName)


New WebClient() <-- Sorry, but what year is it?

Adding headers with user-agent info solved my problem.
 fileReader.Headers.Add("user-agent", "...put here any user-agent info...") 

